# Messages published to AWS SNS topic are not going to SQS Queue which is subscribed to the topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am trying to use AWS SNS and SQS queue together. What I am trying to do achieve is that when I publish a message to the SNS topic, the message will be sent to the SQS queue. Then I will do something with the message in the queue later. I am using FIFO topic and FIFO queue.

I created the topic and queue and subscription using the following code.

```
import { SNSClient, SubscribeCommand, CreateTopicCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";
import {
    CreateQueueCommand,
    SQSClient,
    GetQueueAttributesCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

const qName = `OrderQ.fifo`;
const sqsClient = new SQSClient({});
const topicName = `OrderTopic.fifo`;
const snsClient = new SNSClient({});

const createTopic = async () => {
    try {
        const command = new CreateTopicCommand({
            Name: topicName,
            Attributes: { // for FIFO topic
                FifoTopic: "true",
                ContentBasedDeduplication: "true"
            }
        });

        const result = await snsClient.send(command);

        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

const createQ = async () => {
    try {
        const command = new CreateQueueCommand({
            QueueName: qName,
            Attributes: {
                "FifoQueue": "true"
            }
        });

        const result = await sqsClient.send(command);

        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

/**
 * @param {string} qUrl
 * @param {string} topicArn
 */
const subscribeQToTopic = async (qUrl, topicArn) => {
    try {
        const command = new SubscribeCommand({
            Protocol: "sqs",
            TopicArn: topicArn,
            Endpoint: qUrl,
        });

        const result = await snsClient.send(command);

        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

const createTopicAndSubscription = async () => {
    try {
        const qResult = await createQ();

        const qAttrsResult = await sqsClient.send(new GetQueueAttributesCommand({
            QueueUrl: qResult.QueueUrl,
            AttributeNames: ["QueueArn"]
        }));

        const topicResult = await createTopic();

        const result = await subscribeQToTopic(qAttrsResult.Attributes.QueueArn, topicResult.TopicArn);

        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};

createTopicAndSubscription().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
})
```

The topic, queue and subscription are created without any issue when I run the script.

Then I publish the message to the topic using the ARN of the topic as follow.

```
import {PublishCommand, SNSClient} from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";
    
const topicArn = `topc_arn`;

const snsClient = new SNSClient({
    region: `eu-west-2`,
});

const publishMessage = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await snsClient.send(new PublishCommand({
            Message: "this is the test message", // MESSAGE_TEXT
            TopicArn: topicArn, //TOPIC_ARN
            MessageGroupId: `order_group`,
        }));

        console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

publishMessage();
```

It does not throw any error. The message seems to be published to the topic. But the message is not sent to the queue. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

I got a response like this but the message is not in the queue.

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'ed23d6fb-185e-5487-933a-8bf46b15f727',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  MessageId: 'a5b68fe0-e944-5b6f-bec2-d2ef9a0fe8cf',
  SequenceNumber: '10000000000000008000'
}
```

Comment: How are you testing whether a message is in the SQS queue? Do you have anything else using the queue (eg AWS Lambda function)? If you look at the SNS topic in the management console, does it show the SQS queue as a subscription? If you _manually_ send a message to the SNS topic, does the queue contain a message?

Comment: Hi, I tested both sending the message to the topic running the code I mentioned. I also published a message to the topic in the AWS console. Yes, SQS subscription was created linked to the topic with the status confirmed. But the message count in the Q is still 0.

Comment: You have likely failed to [Give permission to the topic to send messages to the queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/subscribe-sqs-queue-to-sns-topic.html#SendMessageToSQS.sqs.permissions).

Comment: Ah. Could you please show me how I can do that in the code?

Comment: It seems that you need to specify a `Policy` as one of the `Attributes` when calling `CreateQueue()`. See: [CreateQueue - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's the problem with the policy.

Answer (score 0):

We have an example that does this use case successfully in the [AWS Code Lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). However, right now - its implemented in the C++ and Java SDKs. However, looking at this code should point you in the right direction.

[Publish Amazon SNS messages to Amazon SQS queues using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sns_example_cross_MessagesTopicsAndQueues_section.html)

Included is a very detailed Readme as well.